# Why is findViewById returning null?

Tags: android, xml

Relevant parts of onCreate in my application's first Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
  sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

  // ...

}
```

layout/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/sdcard"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="2dp"
  android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
  android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
  android:numColumns="auto_fit"
  android:columnWidth="70dp"
  android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
  android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Was having no problems here, then suddenly despite not even touching any of this code lately I start getting a NullPointerException on `sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));` `findViewById(R.id.sdcard)` is suddenly returning null.

Anyone know why this might happen? Cleaning and rebuilding the project has not helped.

Edit: Solved I guess, the first time I Cleaned it nothing changed but I after cleaning it a second time it works.

Comment: No I did not import it before.

Answer (score 0):

Adapter needs a cursor. Pass a valid cursor and it should work.

Comment: Otherwise i do not see any wrong piece of code here. If the view is a part of your ContentView, you should be able to get a proper id for findviewbyid.

Comment: It does have one, that's just something I omitted in the question